# not able to find correct set of prime numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code for finding prime numbers -

Im not able to figure out as to why my out put contains 33,55,77 an 99

Can any one help in identifying the bug in my code. Im using jupiter notebook. My code is as follows

```
max1 = int(input("find primes up to what number?:"  ))
prime1=[]

for x in range (2,(max1+1)):

    isprime = True
    for i in range (2,int(max1**.50)+1):
        if x%i==0:
            isprime=False
            break
        if isprime:
            if x not in prime1:
                prime1.append(x)

print(prime1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the code in my interpreter, it thinks any odd number is prime, and that's because your `if isprime:` is inside the second for loop, and contains a `break`. Since your for loop starts in a 2, after verifying the number 2 (AKA after verifying if it is even), if it is not, the code classifies it as a prime number, breaks the second for loop, and jumps to the next number. To fix it, all you got to do is put your  `if isprime:` to run AFTER the for loop, just like this:

```
prime1=[]

for x in range (2,(max1+1)):

    isprime = True
    for i in range (2,int(max1**.50)+1):
        if x%i==0:
            isprime=False
            break
    if isprime:
        if x not in prime1:
            prime1.append(x)

print(prime1)
```

Also: little side note: in `for i in range (2,int(max1**.50)+1):`, you are verifing it until the square root of the maximum number, when you could just verify it to the square root of the number itself, like `for i in range (2,int(x**.50)+1):`

Comment: thanks again for the advice about using  the square root of x instead of using the square root of max1